# How to invoke default activity of other application on Android?

Tags: android

How to invoke default activity of other application on Android?  For example, I want my application to invoke a particular pdf reader I have on my phone (i have many pdf reader app)

Comment: Are you the only user of your app?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intents` for it. Here's [example](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/09/sharing-project-assets-with-android-intents.html).

Comment: what intent param if I don't know the name of their activity. I only know the name of applications and their locations on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ACTION_VIEW` Intent with a Uri pointing to the file on the SD card (or `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` in your app-local file store). You should also set the MIME type to be `application/pdf`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("path-to-document"));
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

The code above will launch an activity chooser, in which the user will be able to select the desired app to view the given pdf. I wouldn't suggest enforcing a particular app to be used (since the user might not have it installed on his or her device), but if you must, you can use

```
intent.setPackage("com.package.name")
```

Just make sure you check that the application is installed (or wrap your code in a `try-catch` statement to ensure that an `ActivityNotFoundException` is not thrown).

Comment: I'm pretty sure a 3rd-party app won't be able to view a PDF file (or any file) that has been saved to the app's local (internal) memory. Also, that code won't launch a chooser if the user has a 'default' app set for PDF mime type.

Comment: Alex. That's great to know.   However, I am looking to do something like a shortcut for application that I don't know beforehand what applications will be installed on that phone. Note that the shortcut will be in my app, not the widget provided by Android. Are there a way to register those application into my app so I can invoke them?

Comment: @MisterSquonk, the documentation for [`MODE_WORLD_READABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) suggests otherwise.

Comment: @user1411193, the android activity chooser isn't a "widget", it's an "activity" that is provided by the system and is used (by default) when there are multiple apps that could satisfy a given Intent action. You could always implement your own activity chooser, but I'm not really sure why you want to do this. Is there something wrong with the default activity chooser?

Comment: Alex, I want to skip the activity chooser. For example, if I have two 3nd party app, say, Opera browser and Firefox browswer on my android phone. From my application, i have two buttons: one to open Opera browser and one to Open Firefox. Since I don't know the default activity of these applications(browser), how do I invoke them directly?   I want user to be able to create shortcuts (by creating buttons) for any application on their phone (within my app).

Comment: I am thinking that maybe I can provide a path to the actual application, but I don't know what to put as the intent parameter.  Perhaps, if I can read the Manifest.xml file of other apk, I can find out what their default activity is.  What do you think?

Comment: @Alex : As I understand it, neither `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` nor `MODE_WORD_WRITEABLE` have been implemented in Android - perhaps I'm wrong as I seem to remember this may be related to `SharedPreferences`. But, as I said, a chooser won't be created using that snippet of code you posted if the user has set a 'default' app for a particular mime type.

Comment: Yes, I understand the chooser won't show if a default app is already selected (sorry for not being clear). Also, what do you mean "neither have been implemented in Android"? They are provided as constants in the [**`Context`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) class. Could you clarify?